# Array error on WooCommerce checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am getting an error when I try to checkout with PayPal in WooCommerce. I have no idea what's causing it.

I also have a SagePay plugin, but it happens on either option, no matter what.

```
Warning: array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #1 is not an array in /home/beggar/public_html/development/wp-includes/post.php on line 2996
{"result":"success","redirect":"https:\/\/www.sandbox.paypal.com\/webscr?test_ipn=1&cmd=_cart&business=michael%40thelondonbranch.com&no_note=1¤cy_code=GBP&charset=UTF-8&rm=1&upload=1&return=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fdevelopment%2Fthank-you%2F%3Futm_nooverride%3D1&cancel_return=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fdevelopment%2F%3Fcancel_order%3Dtrue%26_n%3Dc479c487a6&page_style=&invoice=WC-¬ify_url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fdevelopment%2F%3FpaypalListener%3Dpaypal_standard_IPN&no_shipping=1&discount_amount_cart=0.00&item_name_1=Order+%23+-+&quantity_1=1&amount_1=0.00"}
```

This isn't just a warning it seems, as no order is placed in the admin, or emails sent.

I am absolutely stumped on this and it's pretty critical.

Any help greatly appreciated as this is my first time using WooCommerce.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution might be to use a different PayPal payments plugin. I've used Denon's Stripe and Authorize.net plugins and they work well; here is the link to the PayPal one: [PayPal Payments Pro](http://codecanyon.net/item/paypal-pro-credit-card-gateway-for-woocommerce-/1331008?WT.ac=search_thumb&WT.seg_1=search_thumb&WT.z_author=DenonStudio). I'm not affiliated with Denon.

Alternatively, you could squash the error with a little PHP. The warning message you are getting is often because the array has only one value, so it is not really an array.

```
if (is_array($array)) {
    // Do array merge
} else {
    // Don't try to merge, just use value.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I will try it out. I can't use another plugin at this time, but I'll bookmark it for future reference.